# ::after element not showing up when focus

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLXOww), the yellow background works fine when focus.

but [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJegvN), it's not showing.

CSS:

```
.user-label::after, 
.pass-label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 41%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 53%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}


.user-label::after, 
.pass-label::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background: yellow; /*beige;*/ /*#a86bf;*/   
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

**Update:**

I removed the comma on line 89, but why the yellow background displays like that when focus?

Comment: I can see that on your second CodePen, your curled underlines appear. Find this code, and add to it your yellow background code

Comment: you have an extra comma on line 89 ".pass-input:focus + .pass-label::after,"

Comment: In your codepen, you have an extra comma after the last selector on line #89 before the {

Comment: @ChrisLi I removed it, but why the yellow background displays like that when focus?

Comment: im going to try my best to explain, its about how position: absolute works, so when you add height: 50% to an element with position absolute, the height is relative to the first ancestor with position: relative, in your case its <form>, the first one works fine because the <form> element is the at the right height, but you have 2 divs which makes the <form> higher, so the after element is higher too.

Comment: @yalpsid - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMvmzN here is a codepen with somewhat fixed situation. Compare the CSS and see the differences, but basically once you set position:absolute, it look up the nested elements tree to find the closest element with position set (absolute, relative, sticky, fixed) and thats the reference for the top,left,right,bottom of the child. 
I put the position relative to the label so your after pseudoelements have the refference. then i adjusted your scale to match exactly 100%. Best advice is not to use such exact values and that many selectors